# How to solve the error cannot redeclare class in models manager?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

I want to execute a query using the models manager offered by Phalcon Php. I have the following function:

```
public function getSomeData()
{
    return Di::getDefault()->get("modelsManager")->executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM SomeModel WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM AnotherModel)"
        );
    }
}
```

When executing the function above, I get the following error

> Cannot redeclare class ParentDir\Model\SomeModel

However, if I supply the full namespace to the query, it works.

```
SELECT * FROM ParentDir\Model\SomeModel WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ParentDir\Model\AnotherModel)
```

I'm registering `dirs` and `namespaces` in the `di` like this:

```
$parentDir = dirname(__DIR__);

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs([
    $parentDir . "/app/controllers",
    $parentDir . "/app/models"
]);

 $loader->registerNamespaces([
    "ParentDir\\Model" => "$parentDir/app/models/",
    "ParentDir\\Model\\Enum" => "$parentDir/app/models/enum/",
    "ParentDir\\Controller" => "$parentDir/app/controllers/",
    "ParentDir\\Service" => "$parentDir/app/services/",
    "ParentDir\\Locale" => "$parentDir/app/locale/",
    "ParentDir\\Utility" => "$parentDir/app/utility/",
    "ParentDir\\Plugin" => "$parentDir/app/plugin/",
    "ParentDir" => "$parentDir/app/",
]);

$loader->register();
```

Comment: `"However, if I supply the full namespace to the query, it works."` Just do that then?

Comment: @Timothy Doing that would make the query work. However, I would be ignoring the fact that there is a problem in the dependency injector. The official docs do not include the full namespace, as it is the job of the `modelsManager`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating an alias for the namespace?

Failing that modelsManager->createQuery and use pure sql.

Answer (score -1):

It's not modelsmanager, you are just somewhere loading this class with loader two times. Or you have two same classes somehow.